# Digital Ocean droplet & gitlab runner problem

Tags: gitlab-ci, droplet, gitlab-runner

I am recently working on GitLab CI/CD and I want to set up a runner on digital ocean droplet however I get the following error:

```
$ docker network create web
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

how should I avoid this problem, consider that the docker is up and running on the droplet ubuntu with 8 GB ram

Comment: What executor are you using for the runner? If you're using a docker executor, then the problem is your _job_ container doesn't have access to the docker daemon.

Comment: I think the problem is with the executor I have changed the executor to shell executor and it works, however why docker executor does not work on the server ? @sytech

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for confirming that. I'll provide an answer soon that explains this behavior and provides a solution to successfully use the docker executor (which works out better for build isolation)

Answer (score 0):

it can be only one of this reason:

a) gitlab-runner user is not in docker group

```
id gitlab-runner
```

should show something like

```
uid=998(gitlab-runner) gid=998(gitlab-runner) groups=998(gitlab-runner),1001(docker)
```

b) docker service is not running in droplet

Comment: No the gitlab-runner user has access to docker I have checked this multiple times